# How to handle assets in a Sylius theme?

Tags: assets, sylius

I'm new to Sylius and I have many issues handling shop customization. My current issue is adding assets (images, css...) to my custom theme. I've tried every way but I can't figure it out. My questions are:

1. Where are you supposed to put them exactly?
2. How do you get them to the public folder? I tried the `assets:install` and `sylius:theme:assets:install` commands, but since I don't know where to put the files in the first place it didn't really help.
3. How do you reference them in your templates? I can't find where the `asset()` function points to.

**Context**

- I'm using the most recent versions of Sylius Standard (1.7.0), Windows 10 Pro and Firefox
- The theme works, I can select it in the channel settings and I can overwrite the templates and the translations no problem in my `themes/SomethingTheme/SyliusShopBundle` folder

I've seen similar issues on Stack Overflow but they don't seem relevant to this version of Sylius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've placed the public folder of my assets inside the SyliusShopBundle of the theme. These files are copied to the public folder after the command

```
sylius:theme:assets:install
```

is executed.

[Here is a image to my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QytSI.png)

Here a implementation inside the theme

```
<div class="column">
<a href="{{ path('sylius_shop_homepage') }}"><img src="{{ asset('bundles/syliusshop/assets/logo_fitfoods.svg') }}" alt="Sylius logo" class="ui small image" /></a>
```

Comment: Thank you, it does work! Weird logic though, since 1) ours own assets have nothing to do with the ShopBundle and should logically be put in our own theme or bundle and 2) the path used doesn't really exist in the public folder, there's a few missing folders between "bundles" and "syliusshop"... I guess there's a shortcut of some kind somewhere.

Comment: If you are using 1.7 try with webpack encore, I've got my assets in /themes/[theme-name]/assets/... personally.